# Expresso Store - Search on Sale w/ Entry Count

Tags: expresso-store

Is there a way to incorporate the search:on_sale and entries_entries number to display the total number of entries that are on sale?

```
{exp:store:search channel="products" search_id="{segment_3}" search:on_sale="yes"}
{exp:entries_number channel="products"}
{entries_number} Item(s)
{/exp:entries_number}
{/exp:store:search}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use `{total_results}` to show the total. Something along the lines of

```
{exp:store:search channel="products" search_id="{segment_3}" search:on_sale="yes"}
 {if count == 1}
  {total_results} Item{if total_results > 1}s{/if}
 {/if}
All other fields go here 

{/exp:store:search}
```

Will show the total number of returned items